# Display layer with its date in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, date, layer-name

I want to display the image with its date as the layer name, but the following code does not work.

```
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR').filterBounds(roi).filterDate(startdate, enddate).first();
var date = s2.date()
Map.addLayer(s2, {}, ' ' + date, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = s2.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd').getInfo();
```